# How to define a custom property on a dojo gfx shape in a safe way?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have created a shape object through the surface. Now I wish to associate some custom state with it. I can do it in the most straightforward way:

```
var rect = surface.createRect(...);
rect.myCustomData = ...;
```

and hope that no part of dojo or gfx has any logic expecting exactly the same property name.

Is there a way in dojo to safely define custom data on objects produced by it?

P.S.

I could define a property bag using GUID as the propety name. But it is ugly, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way of making sure another part of the JavaScript is relying on that property or not. You could always attempt to validate if it exists before overwriting, for example:

```js
var rect = surface.createRect({
    // Properties
});
if (rect.myCustomData === undefined) {
    rect.myCustomData = myValue;
}
```

But then you're still not  100% sure, maybe some part of the application relies on the property to be non existing. Even if that's not the case, your property can still be overridden.

---

Another way is to provide a seperate "map" containing your custom data, for example by having something like:

```
var rect = surface.createRect({
    // Properties
});

var myCustomData = [ ];
myCustomData.push({
    shape: rect,
    data: myValue
});
```

To retrieve the data you will have to loop through the map, looking if the `shape` property matches your shape and then retrieve the data inside the `data` property.

Then you're sure that no other framework will rely on it, but it means that you have to maintain two seperate parts when creating, updating or deleting shapes.

Comment: The answer could be dojo specific. They could have a hook to keep the custom data.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not the case. If it was then it should be listed in the API docs of the rectangle: http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.9/dojox/gfx.Rect.html